# Can I degrade Google Place Library to a particular version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

My project is using both Google Map JavaScript API and Place Library based on React. But since google upgraded it to v3.39, I met an issue in IE 10. (Some clients are still using IE 10!) The latest version 3.39 doesn't support IE 10, so I tried to degrade it to 3.38 in different ways but none of them working:

1. Pass 'v=3.38' when load Place in header: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.38&key=mykey&libraries=places"></script> -->`. It still loaded v3.39.
2. Manually Load v3.38 Map in header:
   `<!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.38
   &key=mykey&callback=initMap"
   async defer></script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&libraries=places"></script> -->`. The map can be rendered, but address autocomplete will not even show up.
3. Manually load a 3.38 version when render a map: This method partly works. But browser will display an error said: **You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.**

Please give any suggestion on my scenario. Thanks so much!

Comment: First of all, check that you are not loading both the versions of the library (as the error is suggesting), then can you please share the code that you are using at the moment? It will be helpful to debug and let you know which is the problem.

Comment: Hi Ferie, as I mentioned in #2, my autocomplete component worked fine before, and it is also working in 3.39. But if I manually load both v3.38 and place library in header, the dropdown list of address doesn't show up if I type in the <TextField>. I can also see some error message like "Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined", "Uncaught TypeError: _.sa is not a function"...

Comment: Your option #1 should be loading the specified version (3.38). This is literally documented here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#choosing-a-version-number If version 3.39 still loads though, then that means you are overriding this by calling the JS API somewhere else. Can you please post your code?

Comment: @Cui, please, post your code, so we can have a look and debug it. With all this words it is not possible to tell you what is wrong. In any case, remember that errors like the one you are receiving, are not thrown randomly, so be sure not to load multiple time (and maybe with different versions) the library you are using.